# How to preview resource file contents in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, sql, resources

I'm using a resource file to organize custom SQL for my DAL. For a basic example, my repository class (using Dapper) looks like:

```
public class FooRepository : IFooRepository {
    public Foo GetById(int id) {
       using (var con = await GetConnection()) {
            var foo = (await con.QueryAsync<Foo>(
                Sql.Foos.GetById,
                new { FooID = id }
            )).SingleOrDefault();

            return foo;
        } 
    }
}
```

In this case, `Sql.Foos.GetById` is a reference to a resource file, the contents of which are pure SQL, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE FooID = @FooID;
```

However, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to preview the contents of the query. The auto-generated summary for the resource spills out the first few lines (which is all that is needed for simple queries), but doesn't get updated as resources are changed, and for larger files with complex queries this is unhelpful to say the least.

Is there a better way to preview the contents of my SQL resource files (even if it involves storing my queries differently)? My only stipulations are:

1. I'd like to avoid mingling my SQL with my C# if at all possible.
2. I need to be able to write highly-specialized queries, so an ORM is not the answer.
3. Prefer not to use stored procedures (or at least not be confined to them).

Answer (score 0):

You should open up the `ResourceFileName.Designer.cs` from your solution explorer.

[image]

In there you will find all the get methods for your imported sqls and there you can also set the summary manually.

Comment: I don't think this is a reasonable workflow. I shouldn't have to write the same SQL in two places, and even if I did this, for more complex queries the tooltip VS provides lacks formatting and gets truncated.

Comment: Well you could add a descriptive message instead of the whole query. `SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE FooID = @FooID;` could be "Gets all foos with a specific id".
Also a good name for the sql file could give you a big clue as to what it actually does

Comment: Also unfortunately not helpful. "Gets all foos with a specific id" is the method I'm implementing. I want quick access to the actual SQL resource without having to dig through a resource file/file structure.